# Inheritance of jQuery's prototype partially fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance, coffeescript

I want to use Coffeescript to create an UIObject class. This class should inherit from jQuery, so that instances of UIObject can be used as if they where created with jQuery.

```
class UIObject

  isObject: (val) -> typeof val is "object"

  constructor: (tag, attributes) ->
    @merge jQuery(tag, attributes), this
    @UIObjectProperties = {}

  merge: (source, destination) ->
    for key of source
      if destination[key] is undefined
        destination[key] = source[key]
      else if @isObject(source[key])
        @merge(source[key], destination[key])
    return
```

It partially works. Consider the Foobar class below:

```
class Foobar extends UIObject
  constructor: -> super("<h1/>", html: "Foobar")
```

`$("body").append(new Foobar)` works fine. BUT: (new Foobar).appendTo("body") places the tag, but also raises `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Was it just a bad idea to inherit from jQuery? Or is there a solurion?

For those who don't know CoffeeScript, the JavaScript source is:

```
    var Foobar, UIObject;
    var __hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, __extends = function(child, parent) {
        for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; }
        function ctor() { this.constructor = child; }
        ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
        child.prototype = new ctor;
        child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
        return child;
    };

UIObject = (function () {
    UIObject.prototype.isObject = function (val) {
        return typeof val === "object";
    };

    function UIObject(tag, attributes) {
        this.merge(jQuery(tag, attributes), this);
        this.UIObjectProperties = {};
    }

    UIObject.prototype.merge = function (source, destination) {
        var key;

        for (key in source) {
            if (destination[key] === void 0) {
                destination[key] = source[key];
            } else if (this.isObject(source[key])) {
                this.merge(source[key], destination[key]);
            }
        }
    };

    return UIObject;
})();

Foobar = (function () {
    __extends(Foobar, UIObject);

    function Foobar() {
        Foobar.__super__.constructor.call(this, "<h1/>", {
            html: "Foobar"
        });
    }

  return Foobar;
})();
```

Comment: Perhaps jQuery instances have internal references to themselves.

Comment: ... by that I mean that your "merge" function would encounter an infinite recursion problem.  That's a fairly complicated thing to prevent in a deep-copy operation like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bit difficult to achieve (but creative!), since both jQuery and CoffeeScript classes have their ideas about the `.constructor()` method.

In jQuery 1.6.4 (the one used on the CoffeeScript homepage today), an infinite recursion is created at line 246 of jQuery itself, in this line of code:

```
var ret = this.constructor();
```

`this` here points to *your* constructor, but jQuery expect it to point to itself. Your `@merge()` method doesn't replace the constructor correctly. There's an even hackier way out, change your `@merge()` method to:

```
merge: (source, destination) ->
  for key of source
    if destination[key] is undefined
      destination[key] = source[key]
    else if @isObject(source[key])
      @merge(source[key], destination[key])
  @constructor = jQuery
```

Casual testing at 'Try coffeescript' indicated that it works, but I'd be wary that strange effects could manifest later so if you continue with this approach, test throughly.

Comment: It works! Altough i added the constructor copy to the constructor, to prevent it being called recursively. My UIObject constructor looks like this: `element = jQuery(tag, attributes)
    @merge(element, this)
    @constructor = element.constructor`
    @UIObjectProperties = {}`